# ratio of semi-minor axis to semi-major axis

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, noneuclidean-geometry

So I'm writing a paper for a math class on Kepler's equation, and I've ran into a snag on deriving the equation. I've been mostly following the book *Solving Kepler's Equations* by Peter Colwell. I think the problem may be fairly simple, but I have searched and searched and couldn't find anything.

So here's the problem. given the following image
[image: circle-ellipse problem]

Let $a$ and $b$ be the lengths of the semi-major axis and the semi minor axis, respectively, of the ellipse with focus $S$. The author says that the ratio $b/a = PR/QR$. It seems simple but I can't figure out why that is. I'm trying find the justification here.

With the above relationship being shown, it is used to directly show that $rsinv = bsinE$, which is pretty straight forward. I just can't figure out why the equality between the two ratios is true. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

I found a mention of the fact here: http://science.larouchepac.com/kepler/newastronomy/
But that source didn't give any justification either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That outer circle is clearly the auxiliary circle of that ellipse, so the $\angle QCR$ is obviously the eccentric angle of point $P$. In the right triangle $\triangle QCR$, use simple trig to get  $QR=a \cdot \sin\angle QCR$. From the parametrization of the ellipse $(a\cos\theta,b\sin\theta)$ it follows that the ordinate of point $P$ is $PR=b\sin\angle QCR$.

From there it is not a big leap to conclude that $\dfrac{PR}{QR}=\dfrac{b}{a}$

Comment: OOOoooh! OK. That makes a lot of sense now. Wow yeah that was simple. Much appreciated sir.

Comment: It is not recommended to leave thank you notes below answers, just upvote it or accept it if you want to show appreciation. And don't call me sir, because I'm most probably younger than you.